# Preparing data to apply machine learning algorithms for times series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, autocorrelation, methodology, data-preprocessing

I have daily time series financial data. I want to apply machine learning techniques to predict expected returns. To do this, I have first transformed the data so that I could take into account time logic into my model as suggested here ([link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-supervised-learning/))

I have applied the suggested logic in two different ways **after I transformed daily data by dividing daily values with previous day's values and taking their logs (i.e. log(feature1(day2) / feature1(day1))).**

1) 5  daily consecutive values of the predictors and expected return values are used as predictors (features) in the model,

2) 5 values of the predictors and the expected return values from previous weeks (i.e. 1 value from last week, another from two weeks ago and so on)

Here is auto-correlation plot for one of the features.

[image]

As seen from the figure, first consecutive day has significant correlation. Does this affect my model adversely? When I apply the first logic, I get better results compared to the 2nd. However, when checking the most important features, I always observe the previous days as the most important.

What would be your warnings or suggestions?